# no me enlaza la imagen a mi codigo html

Tags: html, html5

estoy haciendo una practica y quiero poner una imagen en especifico (ad.jpg) a mi codigo html pero la imagen no me aparece, ya verifique la ruta y esta bien escrita, es mas cuando cambio e intento con otra imagen del mismo formato jpg (1.jpg) la cual se encuentra en la misma carpeta esta si aparece.

esto me aparece cuando intento con ad.jpg

[image: esto me aparece cuando intento con ad.jpg]

[image: esto me aparece cuando intento con ad.jpg]

y cuando intento con otra imagen esta si aparece

[image: y cuando intento con otra imagen esta si aparece]

[image: y cuando intento con otra imagen esta si aparece]

es la primera vez que me pasa no tengo idea de que pueda ser

el codigo es:

```
<div class="ad container hidden-xs">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <img src="img/ad.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Intenta localizar la imagen con el inspector, para ver sino se sale del área visible de tu página web. Tambien puedes intentar revisar que la imagen que si funciona y la que no funciona tenga el mismo tamaño en pixeles y si el formato de la imagen que estas utilizando es el correcto.

Comment: Por favor, el código en formato texto!

Comment: cuando pongo el inspector de elementos me indica que la imagen se encuentra alli pero por alguna razon le añade un display: none, creo que ha de ser por el plugin de visual studio code, go live

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el código de tu web en algún sandbox, gist, github, drive, dropbox, mega, etc? Desearía saber más acerca de ese archivo `ad.jpg`, la hoja de estilos (para conocer la definición de la clase `ad`) para poder redactar una respuesta. ¿Podrías agregar esto a tu HTML para poder ver el contorno de la imagen? `<img src="img/ad.jpg" alt="" style="border: 2px solid red;" />`. También sería bueno, para las pruebas, eliminar la clase `hidden-xs`.

Comment: si tiene el estilo `display:none` puede ser por el `class=" hidden-xs "` que no se este utilizando bien.

Comment: Si en el inspector te aparece un `display:none`, deberías averiguar qué clase o selector es el que lo está aplicando. Eso se puede mirar en la parte inicial de cada bloque.

Comment: ya me di cuenta de cual es el error, resulta que la imagen tiene el nombre de ad por lo que el adblock me bloqueaba la imagen creyendo que era publicidad

Answer (score 0):

Tu código esta bien solo tienes agregar las etiquetas de ancho ‘width’ y alto ‘hight’ a la imagen, prueba con esto

```
<div class="ad container hidden-xs">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <img src="ad.gif" alt="tu_logo" width="42" hight="42">
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Saludos :)